# What is Ol' George's Nail Wail?

Tags: puzzles

This has been sitting on the bookshelf in my parents' house since I was a kid, and to this day, I still have no idea what it is or how to play:

[image]

It was given to us by my grandma, and the best my dad can remember is that "it's a puzzle of some sort". He claims to have solved it once, but can't recall anything beyond that.

I tried Googling "Ol' George's Nail Wail" to no avail. Here are a couple more pics from other angles:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are the nails all the same length and just the holes are different depths? I could see a puzzle like this using different length nails combined with different depth holes and the end goal is to get all the nails in neatly like in your picture.

Comment: @AndyTinkham Good guess, but I just checked, and all the nails are the same length.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like a "[nail balance](http://www.puzzlesolver.com/puzzle.php?id=5)" puzzle. It is very similar to some of the results of [this Google Image Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=nail%20balance%20puzzle&tbm=isch).

Comment: That's it!! Thanks a ton. And now, here is Ol' George's Nail Wail, SOLVED: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yckYe.jpg

Answer (score 5):

I just purchased one of these from an antique store yesterday. It's a puzzle called nail  balance. You can Google nail balance and find out how to do the puzzle. Included is a picture of the solution.

> [image]